# Audio bandpass using Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, sound

For a mathematics class I am in, my professor is having us manipulate audio files in various ways in order to demonstrate some of the processes we have learned about.

One of these in particular is giving me a lot of trouble. The assignment is to perform a Fourier transform on an audio file, isolate certain frequencies using a step function, and the performing an inverse Fourier transform.

While I understand qualitatively how the problem works, I am having trouble implementing it in Mathematica. I am *somewhat* new to the software, so any tips you can offer would be much appreciated.

The latest iteration of my code imports the file using AudioData[Import[*filename*]] and then performs the Fourier transform using Fourier[*data*], though I am not confident that this is the best method.

Answer (score 2):

> though I am not confident that this is the best method

Why? Fourier does FFT on data. Make sure if your audio has more than one channel to do one at a time.

```
 a = Import["ExampleData/drums.ogg"];
 AudioChannels[a]

 (* 2 *)

 data = AudioData[a];
 Dimensions[data]
 (*  {2, 695674} *)

 ListLinePlot[Abs[Fourier[data[[1, 1 ;; 200]]]]^2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: From there how can I then remove frequencies?

Comment: @Anonymous yes, use BandpassFilter command. You need to provide the cut off frequencies to do that.